# 64-bit ports of 32-bit Apple apps

Tags: catalina, 32-bit

I've delayed updating to Catalina due to a few applications which I will lose access to, due to them being compiled for 32-bit architecture. While the third-party apps are not overly difficult to address, there is one Apple app which I still use and rely on, Pages '09, and cannot go without.*

Are there any ways to find 64-bit ports of 32-bit Apple apps, like Pages '09 ?

---

*Before anyone comments, yes I know that there are newer versions of Pages, but when I'm writing, I much prefer the UI of the older version, so newer versions are a non-option.

Comment: Don‘t think that Apple will rewrite Pages 09 for 64Bit, given that there is a newer version already. If you prefer the old interface you should be able to run Mojave in a VM for this.

Answer (score 1):

There is an application/patch called Retroactive that *might* let you run Pages '09; not quite sure, as the documentation isn't that specific.I know it addresses Aperture, and I plan on trying it after I patch my '11 MBP to run Catalina